# Is 'got me to thinking' correct in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-usage

> A recent article in the Wall Street Journal about a short list of things that desperately need to be ‘de-invented” **got me to thinking** about things in the world of wine that should have never been invented.

I saw the sentence from [here](http://www.princeofpinot.com/article/2123/).I feel "got me to thinking" is not correct. It should be either "*got me thinking*" or "*got me to think*". Any thoughts?

Comment: Define "correct". The cited usage is very "colloquial" (bordering on "slangy", imho), but it's extremely common in casual speech and (informal) text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A recent article in the Wall Street Journal about a short list of things that desperately need to be ‘de-invented” **got me to thinking** about things in the world of wine that should have never been invented.

**got me to thinking** used in the sentence above is correct even if it is uncommon to see it, however it also works using "got me to think" and "got me thinking", the sense is just different.

Comment: Are there any differences among those phrases, "got me to thinking", "got me to think" and "got me thinking"?

Comment: @dan: Strictly speaking, the infinitive-based ***got me to think*** is probably more "syntactically correct" than the continuous participle forms, but idiomatically it's not favoured. My personal opinion is that including ***to*** in ***got me to thinking*** is a little bit more "folksy" than plain ***got me thinking***, but others may feel different. Note that we *never* include ***to*** in ***...started me thinking** [about X]*.